# What scientific evidence is there for a global flood?

Tags: bible, flood-of-noah, science

An atheist has asked me for scientific evidence of a global flood.

He's claimed "ZERO EVIDENCE of a global flood".

I'm not well-read on that.

What scientific evidence is there consistent with Noah's flood?

Comment: [Flood myths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_myth) across the world (from the Biblical [Noah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative) and the Babylonian [Gilgamesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_flood_myth) to the Greek [Atlantis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis) etc.) are based on the global events surrounding the end of the [Last Ice Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Period), about 10,000 BC.

Comment: There is no evidence whatsoever for a global flood. Civilizations thousands of years older than the alledged time of the flood, such as the Ancient Egyptians, make no record of such an event, and there is no archeological evidence whatsoever that the pyramids and other structures were at any time submerged. Furthermore, it would have killed all the trees, and we have living trees older than 4.500 years on Earth.

Comment: Maybe it's the supposed time of the flood that is actually in question.